# Change the class/functionality of a button upon radio click

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, laravel, laravel-4

I have a radio selection in my site that allows a user to choose amongst a number of options.

When the page loads, I would like a button that would take a user to the next step, to be "faded" and not functional.  When a user selects one of the radio options, I would like the button to become active (new link) and opaque (not faded).

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

CSS:

```
#fan_likes .button {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.28),0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.28),inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    background-color: #00d073/*#1abc9c*/;
    border: 1px solid #009d64;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25),inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    color: #fff!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 17px 11px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.faded {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<center>
<div id="fan_likes">
<a href="" class="button faded">Continue</a>
<ul class="facebook-likes">
@foreach($likes_ids as $likes_id) 

<li>
{{$likes_names[$offset]}}
<br>
<input type="radio" name="like" id="{{$likes_id}}" class="input-hidden" value="{{$likes_id}}"  />
<label for="{{$likes_id}}"><img src="/assets/images/loader.gif" data-src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{$likes_id}}/picture?width=200&height=200" width="150" height="150" alt="{{$likes_names[$offset]}}"/></label> 
</li>

<?php $offset++; ?>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
</center>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".input-hidden").find('input:radio').click(function () {
    $("#fan_likes").find('a').removeClass('faded');
});
</script>
```

I am not sure how to write the javascript to achieve what I want.  Any ideas?  I am using Laravel 4 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.facebook-likes li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('faded');
});
```

So, everytime a list item under the class facebook-likes is clicked it will add a class to that list item.

or from an input perspective (must click on the actual input) you could achieve it with something like this:

```
$('.facebook-likes li input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('faded');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/22hmN/

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misunderstood your question, try this:

```
$('.facebook-likes li input').on('click', function() {
    $('#fan_likes a.faded').removeClass('faded');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/22hmN/3/

**EDIT 2**

You say label, but there are images within that label - would it make more sense that they click the image? However, if you do put label there instead of img it works just the same (see: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/22hmN/6/)

Try this:

```
$('.facebook-likes li img').on('click', function () {
    $('#fan_likes a.faded').removeClass('faded');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/22hmN/5/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't what I asked for unfortunately.  I want the button (that says "continue") to change opacity on the click of the radio labels.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood - i'll try again :)

Comment: hmm, this looks like it should work, but isn't.  Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. Without seeing what's running on your machine it's hard to tell. Is the JSFiddle working for you? Perhaps it's a browser issue?

Comment: The jsfiddle does work.  I would like it to work when the radio "label" is clicked, not the radio.  I have stylistically removed the actually radio buttons.

Comment: Ahhh I see! one second. Sorry, it's been a slow morning *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.facebook-likes label').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#fan_likes").find('a').removeClass('faded');
});
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but unfortunately it is not.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try this it may work
$('.facebook-likes).find('label').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#fan_likes").find('a').removeClass('faded');
});